# Allowable syntax for -ms-filter and filter CSS rules

Tags: css, internet-explorer, syntax, sass

I'm trying to get my CSS to pass validation and I have a lot of style rules that look like this:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='../../../public/images/circ_logo_trans_50.png',
    sizingMethod='crop')";
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='../../../public/images/circ_logo_trans_50.png',
    sizingMethod='crop');
```

The validator seems to throw errors when the code is as you see it above. But when I remove the line breaks, it passes.

My understanding is that `-ms-filter` should be followed by a quoted string, whereas `filter` should not.

Is what I've said so far correct? Is there anything else about this syntax that is incorrect?

I stumbled upon this problem when trying to minify the CSS `sass in.scss:out.css --style compact`). When all the code is on a single line, styles at the end stop working because there is something invalid in front. I'm pretty sure it's connected to these filters.

Comment: Is it throwing errors or warnings? The two are different. There are many CSS properties (usually vendor-prefixed) that do not pas 'valiation'. Don't sweat it...the over-riding issue, is "does it work?"

Comment: @Paulie_D I know what you mean about false positives with the validator. My end goal is not validation, but rather to be able to minify the code without it breaking... which I currently cannot do because of an issue (I suspect is) related to invalid code.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your problem is with these filters. Subsequent styling works fine when compiled through Sassmeister with any compression: http://sassmeister.com/gist/1d707346863250ce4c55  I did notice that I clean up whitespace and line breaks from your code whenever I pasted from it. I don't think link breaks are allowed inside the AlphaImageLoader functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of the `-ms-filter` and `filter` properties is absolutely correct.

The important issue with your CSS lies in the syntax of your string. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) explicitly states that a string cannot directly contain a newline. For the purpose of breaking a string over multiple lines in the source itself, simply add backslashes to the end of each line except the last (where the closing quote occurs):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(\
    src='../../../public/images/circ_logo_trans_50.png',\
    sizingMethod='crop')";
```

This will allow the validator to parse your CSS correctly without choking. It *should not* pose problems for IE as it attempts to parse the string for its own use; unfortunately however I can't say for certain that it won't. If it does have problems, then you might have to either

- do away with the line breaks altogether, or
- remove the backslashes and leave these declarations invalid. The next time you validate, comment these lines out to prevent the validator parser from choking.

Note that the unprefixed `filter` property will remain problematic for validation, as it's a non-standard property that does not bear a prefix (prefixes being [the standard way of declaring non-standard properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords), so to speak). That is something you don't have to worry about, of course, knowing that you are using a widely recognized non-standard form of the property.

Comment: +1 Great answer! Can you say a tiny bit more on the relationship between `filter` and `-ms-filter`. The latter I'm used to seeing all the time as a workaround for CSS3 gradients, etc in IE. I know almost nothing about `filter`. If the goal is IE support, can it safely be replaced with the `-ms-filter` version?

Comment: @SDP: IE8 introduced the prefix as a way to comply with the standard that says to use prefixes for vendor-specific properties, so essentially, yes, it does replace the unprefixed version. The unprefixed version was used by IE7 and earlier - if you don't need to support those versions anymore, you can safely remove the unprefixed version entirely.